# Pseudo random number generation for sum of normal-distributed values

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

Les us give N distribution functions $f_{1}, f_{1},... f_{N}$ each for normal distributed random value (with shifted from zero mean vector) on n-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We can construct an arithmetical mean of them which also will be a distribution function for some vector random value. How can I generate random values based on this new random value from uniform distribution?

For N=1 this task can be solved by Box–Muller transform, but what if I need to generate random vectors based on sum of two, three or more normal distributions?

Comment: Are you asking about how to select from a distribution which is the mean of $N$ other distributions, $f(x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{m = 1}^N f_m(x)$ ?

Comment: Yes. The general purpose is to develop algorithm for random values generation for such sums that give me two or more "mean" values, so the calculated values will concentrate near and between them.

Comment: It should be pretty simple, then. To generate a sample from the "total distribution" $f(x)$, just select one of the $N$ "sub-distributions" $f_m(x)$ at random with equal probability, and then use Box-Muller to generate a sample from $f_m(x)$. The overall distribution of such samples should be that of the mean distribution.

Comment: I don't quite understand why. Where is actually a "sum" of values. What if I change arithmetical mean to arbitrary convex sum with weights $\alpha_{m}$?

Comment: I've figured out. In this case I must select sub-distributions with $\alpha_{m}$ probabilities. Please, answer this question, and I will mark it as correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have $N$ probability distribution functions (pdfs) $f_m(x)$.  Since they are pdfs, each of the $f_m(x)$ satisfies $f_m(x) \ge 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\, f_m(x) = 1$. It is assumed that we have a method for generating samples from each of these pdfs. Define their weighted mean $f(x)$ as
$$
f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^N \alpha_m\, f_m(x)\, ,
$$
with weights $0\le \alpha_m \le 1$ such that $\sum_{m=1}^{N}\alpha_m = 1$. $f(x)$ is then also a pdf, since clearly $f(x)\ge 0$ and
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\, f(x) &= \sum_{m=1}^N \alpha_m\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\, f_m(x)\\
&= \sum_{m=1}^N \alpha_m \times 1\\
&= 1\, .
\end{align}

To generate a random sample $X$ from the pdf $f(x)$, first pick a random integer $1\le m\le N$ from the discrete distribution with probabilities $\alpha_m$. ([This link describes methods for this.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26858/how-to-generate-numbers-based-on-an-arbitrary-discrete-distribution)) Then set $X$ equal to a sample generated from the distribution $f_m(x)$.

To see heuristically why this works, imagine generating many samples in this fashion, and filling in a histogram to describe their distribution. Each sample will have a probability $\alpha_m$ of populating the "sub-histogram" associated with $f_m(x)$. Clearly, then, the resulting distribution will be a weighted mean of the "sub-distributions" $f_m(x)$.